# Add Image to Tweet

Tags: iphone, ios5, twitter, uiimage

I have a tweet button in my app which is also hooked up to the code

```
{    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);

    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *screenshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshotImage, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

I need to know how to get the image created with this code onto the

```
[tweetSheet addImage:_______];
```

so they can tweet the image along with their tweet. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bellow method return your current view image

```
-(UIImage *)captureView
{

    CGRect rect = [self.view bounds];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];   
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

and then

```
[tweetSheet addImage:[self captureView]];
```

try this its work...
hope, this help you....

:)

Answer (score -2):

I found the code to do this you just add

```
 [tweetSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"screenshotImage"
                         ]];
```

Comment: it will be [tweetSheet addImage:screenshotImage];

Comment: The `imageNamed:` method only works for images in the app bundle.